# Setup composer.json for updating to lasted version later

Tags: composer

I want to set up my composer.json then able to update the to newest version lately

For example:

module has composer.json

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module",
    "description": "description",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.0",
}
```

after a while I updated the packagist, here's the new composer.json

```
{
    "name": "vendor/module",
    "description": "description",
    "type": "magento2-module",
    "version": "1.0.1",
}
```

But, problem is, when I'm running this command

```
composer update vendor/module
```

The version `1.0.1` does not install, not sure why

Note: I checked the `composer.lock` and also in `vendor/module` to make sure it was installed, but not, `composer show -l` also revealed that `1.0.1` is available

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I might be wrong but I think composer update will just update your composer.json. If you want to actually make the update effective you need to run composer install.